# Does something like Zsys for ZFS exist for btrfs?

Tags: btrfs, zfs

I tried out the Ubuntu 20.04 beta implementation of ZFS, and it comes with something useful called Zsys which automatically creates snapshots when you run upgrades or install new packages etc.
Does something like this exist for btrfs (or even bcachefs) which handles snapshots in an automated way?

Comment: Snapper operates in the same manner for BTRFS on Suse Linux, but I don't know if it has that level of integration on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

There is [apt-btrfs-snapshot](https://launchpad.net/apt-btrfs-snapshot). It is not so well integrated (e.g. it doesn't, as far as I remember, populate the grub menu with options to rollback).

Answer (score 2):

There is a myriad of BTRFS snapshot and backup tools ... there are even tools that will snapshot and send DIFF over ssh to machine on other side of planet. I remember I've seen a write up on Arch linux that had a substantial list ... google is your friend (or even apt-search).
And BTW, don't just jump the gun and go with most recent release of OS if you want to have good selection of tools (devs are busy and often don't port to newest version of OS straight away). Give it 2-5 months and you will be golden.